# What is this difference in the notation for the electric flux density in this closed surface example?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I am currently studying the textbook *Microwave Engineering*, fourth edition, by David Pozar. Section **Fields at a General Material Interface** of chapter **1.3 FIELDS IN MEDIA AND BOUNDARY CONDITIONS** says the following:

> **Fields at a General Material Interface**
> Consider a plane interface between two media, as shown in Figure 1.5. Maxwell's equations in integral form can be used to deduce conditions involving the normal and tangential fields at this interface.
> [image]
> The time-harmonic version of (1.4), where $S$ is the closed "pillbox"-shaped surface shown in Figure 1.6, can be written as
> $$\oint_S \bar{D} \cdot d\bar{s} = \int_V \rho \ dv. \tag{1.29}$$
> In the limit as $h \to 0$, the contribution of $D_\text{tan}$ through the sidewalls goes to zero, so (1.29) reduces to
> $$\Delta SD_{2n} - \Delta SD_{1n} = \Delta S \rho_s,$$
> or
> $$D_{2n} - D_{1n} = \rho_s, \tag{1.30}$$
> where $\rho_s$ is the surface charge density on the interface.
> [image]

$\bar{D}$ is the electric flux density, in coulombs per meter squared (Coul/$\text{m}^2$).

Notice that, in Figure 1.5 and Figure 1.6, we are given $D_{n1}$ and $D_{n2}$, but, in equations (1.30), we are given $D_{1n}$ and $D_{2n}$. Why is there this difference and what does it mean?

Comment: They are the same thing. The  author of the text and the person who drew the figures did not communicate adequately, that's all.

Comment: @mikestone oh, ok. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like this was a mistake by the author or publisher of the textbook. The $n$ in the subscript refers to the normal component of the field, and $1$ or $2$ refers to which material the field is in. Either order--$n1$ or $1n$--means the same thing, but the editor should have made sure the same notation was used throughout.